# How to judge my achievable design frequency on FPGA?

Tags: fpga, frequency, speed

I am coding a design from scratch in VHDL. The FPGA target is a Cyclone V. My design resource occupancy is around 30 % of Logic.

I able to reach a frequency of around 80 MHz. The worst paths are located in large muxes.

I don't have access to other designs to compare mine for this technology (for speed). Some ieee articles and I see 200 MHz.

Is there a kind of rule or formula to estimate the possible achievable frequency on a technology?  To know if my results are good or bad? How to know if 80 or 200 or 300 MHz is a good final speed on a given FPGA?

Comment: I don't think you will find anything short of experience will tell you. Far too many parameters at work between the VHDL design and the architecture of the FPGA.

Comment: 80 Mhz sounds ok. A Mux doesn't *necessitate* a long critical path though, so it sounds like you could still optimize speed by optimizing register placement or pipelining the critical stage

Comment: What do you need?  Does 80 MHz meet your requirement?  If the answer is yes, then to achieve better is just an academic exercise.

Comment: The achievable frequency depends on the architecture of what you are trying to implement.

Comment: My project is a proof of concept so it still does not have any speed requirement. I am more looking for a way to judge if my frequency performance is good or not for that Cyclone V

Comment: I thought that there was a link between the nanometers of an FPGA and achievable frequency

Comment: Design a simple 1 bit toggle counter and timing constraint it to  max clock and push the limits. It will fail timing at some max clock freq. Take it as the maximum achievable frequency on your FPGA.

Comment: One thing to note about FPGA timing is that the synthesiser usually considers that 'good enough is good enough', turn the clock speed up until it fails to meet timing (Synth time will go thru the roof), and then look at the failing paths in the timing report. If you try to synth at 80Mhz, it will consider it complete once it manages to meet that timing, and the fact that you have a tightest path with 50ps of slack means nearly nothing, re run with a 200MHz clock and look at what fails.

Comment: It starts to fail with a constraint of a several MHz more (82-83 MHz) on the same paths which have the smallest slack at 80 MHz meeting timings

Comment: @SteveSh, it is nearly always valuable for a design to meet a better clock speed than its requirements. The margin ensures that the design can be expanded while still meeting the required clock speed. This is valuable for future re-use of the design, re-targeting to other devices and so on. I'm aware that fastest designs can't, etc. I accept that it depends upon the circumstances but it is very good practice to select a design that allows it. Redesigning it afterwards to go faster is usually a slower and harder task than choosing a design on the day that allows it anyway.

Comment: @TonyM - I agree with a lot of what you said.  And back in the days when I was doing FPGA designs, I too would crank up the clock speed a bit to see where the design would break, then go and add some pipeline registers to bring things back into compliance. But I cold have gone down that rabbit hole ad-nauseum.  Another way to look at it is that redesigning it to go faster means that your requirements weren't that well defined in the first place, or else changed.

Comment: Thanks, @SteveSh. I have to emphasise that it's not a case of trying to speed the design up afterwards but choosing a design approach that builds slack in. Just a good policy, no different in principle or reasoning to not loading up a power supply system to the last mA at max. possible draw. The requirements probably won't cover future re-use of the design in a new project that expands or adds on to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

80MHz is pretty low, it was my target for the Xilinx Virtex in the late 1990s.
(125 MHz in Virtex-II Pro, 187MHz in Virtex-5 from simple ports of the same design)

If you have a good feel for your design, pick the likely most critical component and implement that; and re-pipeline it until you're happy with the result. Return to the complete design with what you have learned.

Starting with the Virtex-5 result at 187MHz, I took a key element (a floating point square root operator delivering 1 root per clock), re-pipelined it and doubled the speed (adding 50% to the pipeline length and latency) - somewhere between 350 and 400 MHz. Project folded unfortunately, before I could extend that result to the whole design.

A related approach is to look at the speed of an ALU, e.g. a 32-bit one ... it tends to be among the slower components because of the carry chain. I read (back in the Pentium Pro days) that Andy Glew worked out an ALU architecture with 12 or 14 gate delays, and then forced the rest of the CPU to keep up with that.

Comment: Thanks for sharing experience. So if you were reaching 80 MHz in the end of 90's and I am at 80 MHz in an FPGA of 2011, it sounds that my design isn't good

Comment: If you only need 80MHz then your design is good!

Answer (score 0):

There's too many variables here...how does clock distribution work, what combinational logic appears throughout the circuit between latch elements, and the precise routing of signals.

The best approach is to simulate and synthesize the design.  The synthesis tool will (at least) work to achieve your clock goals, and let you know if they've been met with a certain part or speed grade.  Even so, you should simulate the fully synthesized design, and if it were me I'd use 90-100MHz rate just for margin.